# Django Model Management in the shell

Tags: python, django

I'm having a trouble understanding the process of 'making an instance(or a row in DB table) of the model in the shell', because I think it conflicts the plain python knowledge - class/instance attribute and instantiation.

Following is from the example in Django official documents.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the code describing the model 'Blog'.

```
>>> from blog.models import Blog
>>> b = Blog(name='Beatles Blog', tagline='All the latest Beatles news.')
>>> b.save()
```

And the shell prompt follows.
In the second line, the right hand side is just the perfect instantiating form from python, writing the class name and then assigning values in arguments inside the parentheses, right?

But problem here is,  'name' and 'tagline' is defined as class attributes, not instance variables. If the code makes sense, then it should be like:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        tagline = models.TextField()
```

How can the class be instantiated using class variable?

P.S
One possibility, I guess, is that the manager API which intermediates DB table and the user does all the job, and the obscure code above is the following result. BUT I'm not sure.

Comment: It has to do with metaclasses...

Comment: @thebjorn thank you! Could you give me a more concrete explanation?

Comment: Metaclasses changes how classes are created. It's a complex topic, not really amenable for a QA site. Google has many pointers, this being the first one: https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/

Comment: @thebjorn thank you again! But, sir, according to the answer by Kevin below, it seems that it can be explained with using keyword arguments in the '__init__' method, without metaclass. Is the answer below also related to meta class? // Sorry, I'm such a dumb. I myself forgot the core of the question. I added the comment to the answer below.

Comment: Models are not just used for instance creation -- so while Kevin's answer shows you how instance and class attributes work, it is unrelated to how Django models are implemented.  You can check the source yourself, the `Model` class is defined at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L394 (the metaclass is defined above it in the same file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some aspects of the Django ORM certainly are advanced, the specific behavior you're asking about here is actually straightforward Python, because in Python there's a distinction between class and instance attributes. You can find lots of existing information on that distinction.

Perhaps this sample code will make things clearer:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)

class Blog(Model):
    name = 'class'

>>> b = Blog(name='instance')
>>> b.name
'instance'
>>> b.__class__.name
'class'
>>> b.name = 'new name'
>>> b.name
'new name'
```

To be clear, I'm not saying that this how Django models actually work, I'm just demonstrating that this particular distinction between class and instance attributes is part of Python, not something particular to Django.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! But the variables you used in the answer is actually class attributes, not instance variables. The main idea of my questions, is about the usage of 'class attribute'(not instance variable) in instantiating the object.

Comment: @Rhee: My answer uses both class attributes and instance attributes, and the point is to show the distinction. The declaration in the model definition becomes a class attribute. The keyword argument used in instantiation is turned into an instance attribute by `Model.__init__`. They are different attributes that happen to have the same name.